# pcolormesh plot from x,y,z data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data in a textfile in tableform with three columns. I use np.genfromtxt to read all the columns into matplotlib as x, y, z.

I want to create a color meshplot where x and y are the coordinates and z represents the color, i think people refer to such a plot as heatmap.

My code is as follows:

```
x = np.genfromtxt('mesh.txt', dtype=float, delimiter=' ', usecols = (0))
y = np.genfromtxt('mesh.txt', dtype=float, delimiter=' ', usecols = (1))
z = np.genfromtxt('mesh.txt', dtype=float, delimiter=' ', usecols = (2))

xmesh, ymesh = np.meshgrid(x,y)
diagram1.pcolormesh(xmesh,ymesh,z)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
line 7154, in pcolormesh
C = ma.ravel(C[0:Ny-1, 0:Nx-1]) # data point in each cell is value at
IndexError: too many indices
```

The textfile is as follows:

```
1 1 5
2 1 4
3 1 2
4 1 6
1 2 6
2 2 2
3 2 1
4 2 9
1 3 7
2 3 4
3 3 3
4 3 5
1 4 3
2 4 4
3 4 7
4 4 6
```

How is this to solve.

Answer (score 7):

In the example data provided above, x, y, and z can be easily reshaped to get 2D array. The answer below is for someone who is looking for more generalized answer with random x,y, and z arrays.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import numpy

# use your x,y and z arrays here
x = numpy.random.randint(1,30, 50)
y = numpy.random.randint(1,30, 50)
z = numpy.random.randint(1,30, 50)

yy, xx = numpy.meshgrid(y,x)
zz = griddata(x,y,z,xx,yy, interp='linear')
plt.pcolor(zz)
#plt.contourf(xx,yy,zz) # if you want contour plot
#plt.imshow(zz)
plt.pcolorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `from matplotlib.mlab import griddata` doesnt seem to work anymore, and `griddata` is now replaced with a different syntax in `scipy.interpolate`. Would it be possible to update this useful answer?

Comment: `cannot import name 'griddata' from 'matplotlib.mlab'`

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that x, y and z will be read as one-dimensional vectors of the same length, let's say N. The problem is that when you create your `xmesh` and `ymesh`, they are N x N, which your z values should be as well. It's only N, which is why you are getting an error.

What is the layout of your file? I'm guessing each row is a (x,y,z) that you want to create a mesh from. In order to do this, you need to know how the points are ordered as a mesh (either as row-major or column-major). Once you know this, instead of creating `xmesh` and `ymesh`, you can do something like this:

```
N = np.sqrt(len(x)) # Only if squared, adjust accordingly
x = x.reshape((N, N))
y = y.reshape((N, N))
z = z.reshape((N, N))
pcolormesh(x, y, z)
```

Before doing this, I would start by doing this:

```
scatter(x, y, c=z)
```

which will give you the points of the mesh, which is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and agree with Gustav Larsson's suggestion to use

```
scatter(x, y, c=z)
```

In my particular case, I set the linewidths of the scatter points to zero:

```
scatter(x, y, c=z, linewidths=0)
```

of course, you can play around with other decorations, color schemes etc., the reference of [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) will help you further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are plotting X and Y as 2D arrays while Z is still a 1D array. Try something like:

```
Znew=np.reshape(z,(len(xmesh[:,0]),len(xmesh[0,:])))
diagram1.pcolormesh(xmesh,ymesh,Znew)
```

**Update:** Tou have a X/Y grid of size 4x4:

```
x = np.genfromtxt('mesh.txt', dtype=float, delimiter=' ', usecols = (0))
y = np.genfromtxt('mesh.txt', dtype=float, delimiter=' ', usecols = (1))
z = np.genfromtxt('mesh.txt', dtype=float, delimiter=' ', usecols = (2))
```

Reshape the arrays as suggestet by @Gustav Larsson and myself like this:

```
Xnew=np.reshape(x,(4,4)) 
Xnew=np.reshape(y,(4,4))
Znew=np.reshape(z,(4,4))
```

Which gives you three 4x4 arrays to plot using pcolormesh:

```
diagram1.pcolormesh(Xnew,Ynew,Znew)
```

Comment: I tried this and got the error: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: The reshaped array must have the same total number of elements as the original array. Try to write out the size of the arrays to make sure that your reshaped array is the same as the original (after you read data from file, but before you reshape): "print x.shape, y.shape, z.shape".